# Powershell - Mail Message Body will not do new lines

Tags: powershell, mailmessage

I have been racking my brain for hours.   All I want is the following.

202011.txt

```
3   12/28/2020 4:22:56.008 PM   Front                   MOTION
10  12/28/2020 4:23:02.619 PM   Joessomebody            ::ffff:10.60.0.169: Login
3   12/28/2020 4:23:30.610 PM   Front                   MOTION
3   12/28/2020 4:24:05.131 PM   Front                   MOTION
```

It keeps looking like this in the email

3   12/28/2020 4:22:56.008 PM   Front                   MOTION
10  12/28/2020 4:23:02.619 PM   Joessomebody             ::ffff:10.60.0.169: Login
3   12/28/2020 4:23:30.610 PM   Front                   MOTION
3   12/28/2020 4:24:05.131 PM   Front                   MOTION

```
$SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient

$MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage

$SmtpClient.Host = "campus.Test.com"

$mailmessage.from = ("No-Reply@Test.org")

$mailmessage.To.add("Me@Test.org")

function Get-LastLinesNew
{
$v = Get-Content -Path "C:\BlueIris\log\202011.txt" -Tail 5
return ($v)
}
$mailmessage.Subject = “Alert - NVR - Blue Iris - Logs”

<#$mailmessage.Body = “Alert Body with Instruction to recipients”#>

$file = "C:\BlueIris\log\202011.txt"

$attach = Get-LastLinesNew
$attach = $attach -replace "'r'n","<br />"
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$attach    #For Testing 
$MailMessage.body = $attach -replace "'r'n","<br />"
$MailMessage.body #For Testing
pause   #For Testing

try
{
    $smtpclient.Send($mailmessage)
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] 
{
    $MailMessage.Attachments.Dispose()
    $MailMessage.Body = "File Size to large, ERROR"
    $MailMessage.Subject = "NVR ERROR"
    $smtpclient.Send($MailMessage)

}
```

I just stripped down the function to the bare minimum and its still fails

```
$MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
$attach = Get-Content -Path "\\NVR\c$\BlueIris\log\202011.txt" -Tail 5
$attach = $attach -replace "'r'n","<br />"
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $True
$attach
$MailMessage.body = $attach
$MailMessage.body
pause
```

[image: REsult]

Also  PSVersion                    5.1.19041.610

Comment: What version of PS are you running?

Comment: Also  PSVersion                    5.1.19041.610

Comment: It should be `"backtick n"` instead of single quote. You could also try the regex version `$attach -replace '\r?\n','<br />'`

Comment: It has something to do with this line

$MailMessage.body = $attach

Thats when I lose the <br />

Answer (score 1):

In the end I needed to add Out-String as a piped command to the Get-Content

```
function Get-LastLinesNew
{
$v = Get-Content -Path "C:\BlueIris\log\202011.txt" -Tail 5 | Out-String
return ($v)
}
```

Just like that and it worked like a dream.  I am guessing that the powershell shell has some sort of auto formatting built into it that allowed it to show all the strings as one string when using the replace command and then showing it on the screen.  Once it went to the mail message it read it as an array again and lost all the formatting.   Weird but solved.   Thanks everyone!!!!

Answer (score 0):

A couple other options is to use **[System.IO.File]** or the **-raw** flag with Get-Content because Get-Content returns an array of lines.

#### System.IO.File Option

```
function Get-LastLinesNew
{
  $v = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\BlueIris\log\202011.txt")
  return ($v)
}
```

#### Get-Content -Raw

```
function Get-LastLinesNew
{
  $v = Get-Content -Path "C:\BlueIris\log\202011.txt" -Raw
  return ($v)
}
```